# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined" while using stripe payment method Stripe.charges.create({}) in angularJS/NodeJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, stripe-payments

Hello I am new to AngularJS and working on a project where i am creating a payment form with stripe. I have create the form and create my JS code as described in the stripe's website. I am getting true response for card verification but payment method gives me this error on console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined",

Following is my HTML code:

```
<div class="checkout_popup" id="checkout_popup">
    <div class="col-md-12"><h3>Form</h3></div>
    <form id="payment-form" method="post">
    <div class="col-md-12"><input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" /></div>
    <div class="col-md-12"><input type="text" id="card-number" data-stripe="number" value="4242424242424242" placeholder="Card Number (16 Digit)"/></div>
    <div class="col-md-12"><input type="text" id="card-cvc" placeholder="cvc" data-stripe="cvc" value="123" /></div>
    <div class="col-md-12"><input type="text" id="card-expiry-month" data-stripe="exp_month" value="12" placeholder="Month Expire" /></div>
    <div class="col-md-12"><input type="text" id="card-expiry-year" data-stripe="exp_year" value="2017" placeholder="Year Expire" /></div>
    <div class="col-md-12"><input type="button" id="pay-now" value="Pay Now" ng-click="submitstripe()" /></div>
    </form>
</div>
```

and this the JS code:

```
.controller('UserAccountController', function($scope, $http, $state, $stateParams, $filter) {
 $scope.submitstripe = function(){
        console.log('ready stripe');


        Stripe.card.createToken({
        number: document.getElementById('card-number').value,
        cvc: document.getElementById('card-cvc').value,
        exp_month: document.getElementById('card-expiry-month').value,
        exp_year: document.getElementById('card-expiry-year').value
        }, stripeResponseHandler);
        return false;
    };
})

function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {

        if (response.error) { // Problem!
            console.log(response.error.message);
        } else { // Token was created!
            // Get the token ID:
            var token = response.id;
            // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server:
            console.log('Credit card verified, your token is : '+token);

            var email = document.getElementById('email').value;

            var charge = Stripe.charges.create({
            amount: 10, // Amount in cents
            currency: "usd",
            source: token,
            description: "test charges"
            }, function(err, charge) {
            if (err && err.type === 'StripeCardError') {
                // The card has been declined
                alert('Your card is not valid');
            }

            document.getElementById('card-number').value = '';
            document.getElementById('card-cvc').value = '';
            document.getElementById('card-expiry-month').value = '';
            document.getElementById('card-expiry-year').value = '';
            document.getElementById('checkout_popup').style.display = 'none';
            alert('payment successfull'); 
            });
       }
    }
```

Comment: You get this error when Stripe or Stripe.charges are undefined. Put a bebugger point and make sure both objects are defined

Comment: @RaviTeja but this method is working  Stripe.card.createToken({ }), that doesn't mean that stripe is defined already?

Comment: Probably, yes. Then make sure strip.charges is also defined. You can console.log(Stripe) and verify whether there is an charges object in Stripe object.

Comment: @RaviTeja it prints function a(){} when i console.log(Stripe)

Comment: What? Can you put debugger point on `var charges = Strip.`... line and see whether it contains charges object?

Comment: Are you using `Angular-stripe`? https://github.com/bendrucker/angular-stripe?

Comment: no angular alone and embedded stripe js

Comment: var charge = Stripe.charges.create({
console.log(Stripe);
Like this you say?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to process the charge on the client side. But the documentation states:

> Use Stripe's API and your server-side code to process charges.

The client side library is different from the NodeJS library. You're trying to call `stripe.charges` on the client library that doesn't exist. This logic should be created on the Server side.

If you check the source code for the Client side library [here](https://js.stripe.com/v2/) you will see that the `charges` object doesn't exist.

Instead, it's available [here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/lib/resources/Charges.js) in the NodeJS library

Comment: Yes i think you are right, i have created a $http.post() method in my angular controller and created a post method in my node app.js to handle the post data. Now its not showing me the error. But payment is still not reach to my stripe account. I am very near